# CakePHP why does my appcontroller not work for admin?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

For some reason beforefilter is not executed in appcontroller when I am in the admin section.

I test it with `die();` and it still goes through. What could be the problem?

When I am logged out, it forwards to login, appcontroller is executed. When I log in, I get the problem.

Router:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'static', 'action' => 'index'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
/**
 * PLUGIN MATCH
 */
if ($plugins = Configure::listObjects('plugin')) {
    $pluginMatch = implode('|', array_map(array('Inflector', 'underscore'), $plugins));
    Router::connect( "/:language/:plugin/:controller/:action/*",  array('action' => null),  array('plugin' => $pluginMatch)    );
}
/**
 *  ADMIN
 */
Router::connect('/:language/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('action' => null,   'admin'=> true),  array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/:language/admin', array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'),  array('language' => '[a-z]{3}')); //...and set the admin default page
/**
 * LANGUAGES
 */
Router::connect('/:language/home', array('controller' => 'static', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:language/about', array('controller' => 'static', 'action' => 'about'));
// ...and more of those regular redirects here
```

Appcontroller beforeFilter:

```
function beforeFilter(){
    die();
    // LANGUAGES
    $this->_setLanguage();

    $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions'; //  CAN SOMEBODY EXPLAIN TO ME WHAT THIS DOES?
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array( 'controller' => 'static', 'action' => 'index', 'language'=>$this->Session->read('Config.language'));
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array( 'controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'index', 'language'=>$this->Session->read('Config.language'));
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array( 'controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login', 'plugin'=>null,'language'=>$this->Session->read('Config.language'));
    // ACO
    $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/'; // The main ACO. Maybe we need to change something for languages?
    if($this->Auth->user()){
        $this->set('u', $this->Auth->user());
    }
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: does the specific controller have a beforeFilter? and does it call parent::beforeFilter?

Comment: uhm...right. Wanna write the answer, so I can mark it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does the specific controller have a beforeFilter? and does it call parent::beforeFilter?

the simple stuff sometimes is overlooked.

Comment: At most, this answer implies a solution, but ideally it should explicitly state how to resolve the problem without asking any questions.  If the question is not clear enough to do so, then the question should be closed as Needs Debugging Details.